# Android configuration for 3.1.3 - mobile testing with Appium

Tags: appium-ios, appium-android, appium-desktop

I have registered myself with udemy.com tutorials on Appium testing but all given steps are in configuration w.r.t. for old Android Studio version like 2.x. 
Now the latest version of Android Studio is 3.1.3 and after installing i could not find sdk and tools folder. How to set the path and classpath for android 3.1.3 version for Windows to use with Appium.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio 3.*:**

> Tools > SDK Manager > Edit "Android SDK Location"

**Android Studio 2.*** 
SDK location for all projects from the top menu:

Try this way i try in Android Studio 2.0

1. File -> Settings
2. Settings -> SDK option
3. Click Edit option in SDK Location
4. Show "SDK Components Setup"
5. Click on Tree "..." in "SDK Components Wizard"
6. Select your new SDK Path

and for Windows:

1. Click on File menu.
2. Select Project Structure.
3. Edit the path in SDK Location text box. From the next time Android Studio will use this location for all your projects.

After that, Set environment variable $ANDROID_HOME to your new SDK location

Hope this helps,